# I have converted an Active directory network account to a mobile one on my Mac and now I can't login at all

Tags: active-directory, mac-osx

I have converted an Active directory network account to a mobile one and now I can't login at all

it is an imac with El Capitan 10.11.1. We connected it to the network and bound it to our Active Directory Server (Windows Server 2008 R2) so that users could login with their active directory credentials with a local home directory. The we had to use it while it was disconnected from the network ( and the AD server) and we got the message "network accounts unavailable". We converted the network account to a mobile one and now when ever we try to login with that user the wheel keeps turning indefinitely and we cant login. Network user that were not converted can still login (when connected to the network).

I do not have any experience with macs but I am the IT guy saddled with this one. It is the only mac in our organisation. I have a local admin user to do stuff on the mac. I have access to the AD server if I need it. I have searched this forum and the web and I can't find a solution.

Thanks in advance
Chariton